# Counterexample for given statement?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Given statement is true or false?

> If $f$ is a polynomial such that $f'(2)=0$ and $f''(2)=0$ then $f$ has a critical point at $x=2$ which is neither a local minimum nor a local maximum.

---

My attempts:

Since $2$ is a inflection point in this question,so it is neither a local maximum nor a local minimum,so i answered it True.But in my book this is given False.I do not understand why.

Comment: How about $f(x)=(x-2)^4$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since f ′′ (2)=0, we can not conclude. If f ′′ (2) was positive, that would be a local min.; if negative, a local max. Now, we cannot say. So the answer given is true.

Comment: Give an example of a polynomial such that the second derivative test fails but the polynomial has a local max or min

Comment: $f(x)=1-x^4$ has a local max. at $x=0$, but the first and the second derivatives vanish at this point.